# Launch settings iphone5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Ok, I believe I have a problem with the launch setting not fitting iPhone 5. This is not a splash issue because the status bar is about an inch away from the top . This is what happens as soon as the splash screen comes on. How do I optimize it to launch with iPhone 5 support?

Comment: Did you add a `Default-568h@2x.png` wich is 640X1136 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do as folllows, I hope you might get some help.

Set a 4-inch launch image for your app. for that you have to get 1136px screen height ..otherwies you will get black screen